# detached entity passed to persist Spring JPA

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Getting error as "detached entity passed to persist: com.technople.domain.Role; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.technople.domain.Role" while saving data

RolePrivilegesX Code Snippets

```
@Entity
@Table(name="role_privileges_X")
@NamedQuery(name="RolePrivilegesX.findAll", query="SELECT r FROM RolePrivilegesX r")
public class RolePrivilegesX extends AbstractBaseEntity{
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
    private Role role;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
    private Company company;
    private String privileges;

    public Role getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(Role role) {
        this.role = role;
    }
}
```

Role Snippets

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role extends AbstractBaseEntity {
      @OneToMany(mappedBy = "role", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<RolePrivilegesX> rolePrivilegesXs;
   public void setRolePrivilegesXs(List<RolePrivilegesX> rolePrivilegesXs) {
        this.rolePrivilegesXs = rolePrivilegesXs;
    }

    public void setRecordAssignment(RecordsAssignment recordAssignment) {
        this.recordAssignment = recordAssignment;
    }

    public RolePrivilegesX addRolePrivilegesX(RolePrivilegesX rolePrivilegesX) {
        if (getRolePrivilegesXs() == null) {
            setRolePrivilegesXs(new ArrayList<>());
        }
        getRolePrivilegesXs().add(rolePrivilegesX);
        rolePrivilegesX.setRole(this);

        return rolePrivilegesX;
    }

    public RolePrivilegesX removeRolePrivilegesX(RolePrivilegesX rolePrivilegesX) {
        List<RolePrivilegesX> rolePrivilegesXs = getRolePrivilegesXs();
        if (null == rolePrivilegesXs) {
            rolePrivilegesXs = Lists.newArrayList();
        }
        rolePrivilegesXs.remove(rolePrivilegesX);
        rolePrivilegesX.setRole(null);;

        return rolePrivilegesX;
    }
    }
```

AbstractBaseEntity Code Snippets

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class AbstractBaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
}
```

RoleServiceImpl code snippets

```
@Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public RoleForm saveOrUpdate(RoleForm roleForm) {
        Company company = loggedInCompany();
        Employee loggedInEmployee = loggedInEmployee();
        Role role = null;
        if (null != roleForm.getRoleId()) {
            role = roleRepository.findOne(roleForm.getRoleId());
        }
        if (null == role) {
            role = new Role();
            role = assignNewRolePrivileges(roleForm, role);
        } else {
            List<RolePrivilegesX> rolePrivilegesXs = role.getRolePrivilegesXs();
            if (null == rolePrivilegesXs || rolePrivilegesXs.isEmpty()) {
                role = assignNewRolePrivileges(roleForm, role);
            } else {
                rolePrivilegesXs.forEach(rolePrivilegesX -> rolePrivilegesX.setDeleted(Boolean.TRUE));
                RolePrivilegesX rolePrivilegesX = createNewRolePrivileges(roleForm, role);
                rolePrivilegesXs.add(rolePrivilegesX);
            }
        }
        role.setCompany(company);
        role.setCreatedBy(loggedInEmployee.getName());
        role.setDeleted(Boolean.FALSE);
        role.setName(roleForm.getName());
        role.setParent(findRole(roleForm.getReportsTo()));
        Role savedRoles = roleRepository.save(role);
        return new RoleForm(savedRoles);
    }
```

Role Repository Snippet

```
package com.technople.repository;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.technople.domain.Company;
import com.technople.domain.Role;

public interface RoleRepository extends JpaRepository<Role, Long>{
    List<Role> findByCompanyAndDeleted(Company company, Boolean deleted);
}
```

I have gone through lot of similar questions but that didn't solve my problem. Please suggest me what I'm doing wrong in this.

Comment: can you post your roleRepository.save method

Comment: @Tom I have updated the question

Comment: do you use `new`operator in the `createNewRolePrivileges(roleForm, role);` method? (as the method name supposes)

Answer (score 4):

I feel most likely the problem is with the cascade type where in you need to use  the `CascadeType.MERGE` instead of `CascaCadeType.ALL`.

Comment: Changing the cascade type from ALL to MERGE resolves the Issue. How ever in my case the nested objects are not assigned Id columns (which are Auto generate annotation) !!

Comment: Also i tried to keep the cascade type to ALL and before saving doing a refresh using the entity Manager and still getting the same error. Not sure why refreshing the Object doesn't resolve the issue !!

Answer (score 3):

Never mind . My Issue got resolved when i set the cascade type properly on  bi directional relationship. Earlier i only had the cascade type set on Parent and after setting it on the child everything is working as expected.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can set the cascade type to `Persist` instead of `All`.
This will solve the issue, as you have already annotated the function with `transactional`